# How to return millisecond information for File Access on Mac Os X (in Java)?

Tags: java, macos, file-io

I just recognized that Mac Os X does not return any millisecond information to `java.io.File#lastModified()` method.

The long values are rounded, so the most specific kind of information is the second after transfer to a `DateTime` Object.

Is there a way to get those information some other way, maybe through the `java.nio.file.Files#readAttributes(Path,Class,LinkOption[])` method, or want it be possible to distinguish between milliseconds?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a limitation of the file system, not of the Java API.  According to the [format specification](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn/tn1150.html#HFSPlusDates) HFS+ only stores timestamps to a granularity of one second.