# R file.mtime() extremely poor precision on Mac OS and Windows 7

Tags: r, timestamp, filemtime

On Windows 7 and Mac OS 10.12.2 (with R 3.3.2), it appears that `file.mtime()` severely rounds or truncates timestamps. I verified that `file.create("my_file.txt"); print(as.numeric(file.mtime("my_file.txt")), digits = 22)` prints out several digits past the decimal on Linux, but everything past the decimal disappears on Windows 7 for the same `my_file.txt`. The behavior for Mac OS 10.12.2 is similar to that of Windows 7. Is there a platform-independent way to get precise file timestamps in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the new `file.info` is likely the best way to go. If R-3.3.3 does not bring what you need (or in the interim, if it will), you can try to side-step it by capitalizing on the fact that `stat` is likely installed in the base OS (I have not tested on a Mac):

```
as.POSIXct(system2("stat", args = c("-c", "%y", "my_file.txt"), stdout = TRUE))
# [1] "2017-02-15 11:24:13 PST"
```

This can be formalized in a function that does a skosh more for you:

```
my_mtime <- function(filenames, stat = c("modified", "birth", "access", "status"),
                     exe = Sys.which("stat")) {
  if (! nzchar(exe)) stop("'stat' not found")
  stat <- switch(match.arg(stat), birth = "%w", access = "%x", modified = "%y", status = "%z")
  filenames <- Sys.glob(filenames) # expand wildcards, remove missing files
  if (length(filenames)) {
    outs <- setNames(system2(exe, args = c("-c", stat, shQuote(filenames)), stdout = TRUE),
                     nm = filenames)
    as.POSIXct(outs)
  }
}

my_mtime("[bh]*")
#                  b-file.R                  h-file.R 
# "2017-02-14 05:46:34 PST" "2017-02-14 05:46:34 PST"
```

Since you asked for `file.mtime`, I'm assuming "modified" is the most interesting to you, but it's easy enough to include some other file timestamps:

```
my_mtime("[bh]*", stat="birth")
#                  b-file.R                  h-file.R 
# "2017-02-13 22:04:01 PST" "2017-02-13 22:04:01 PST" 
my_mtime("[bh]*", stat="status")
#                  b-file.R                  h-file.R 
# "2017-02-14 05:46:34 PST" "2017-02-14 05:46:34 PST"
```

Note that the lack of fractional seconds is an artifact of printing (as you stated), this can be remedied:

```
x <- my_mtime("[bh]*", stat="status")
x
#                  b-file.R                  h-file.R 
# "2017-02-14 05:46:34 PST" "2017-02-14 05:46:34 PST" 
options(digits.secs = 6)
x
#                         b-file.R                         h-file.R 
# "2017-02-14 05:46:34.307046 PST" "2017-02-14 05:46:34.313038 PST" 
class(x)
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

**Update**: after testing on a Mac, I confirmed a couple of things (thanks to @HongOoi for the prod): (1) `stat` is indeed different, not supporting the same command-line options, so this script would need to be updated; and (2) [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18404059/3358272) suggests that the filesystem is not even storing sub-second resolution on the file times. If your filesystem type is HFS+, I think there may be nothing to be done here. If the underlying filesystem is different, you may have better results.

It's true that Windows does not come with a `stat` executable. However, [Git for Windows](http://git-for-windows.github.io/) (which some argue is a necessity in an analyst/dev toolkit) does, under `/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/stat.exe`. (In fact, my hack above was written on Windows, tested second on Ubuntu.)

Bottom line, unfortunately, you may not get what you want/need on MacOS depending on your filesystem type. I could not get the installed `stat` to give sub-second resolution (even with its different arguments), suggesting that the 4 year old answer I referenced has not changed.

Comment: stat is a Unix/Linux utility, not present on Windows. On Mac, the filesystem itself only stores times with 1-second resolution (until APFS arrives). This basically doesn't do anything more than R's `file.info` does already.

Comment: Note that Visual Studio comes with git integration built in, so you don't even need a standalone git install necessarily.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks. Does VS come with other unix-y executables like `stat`? (Didn't think to check VS since it wasn't in the question, perhaps the OP can use this.)

Comment: No, but on Windows 10, you can use stat itself [inside a bash shell.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/commandline/wsl/about)

Comment: Sure it is, and you can even "see" the executable at `%HOME%\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\bin\stat`. To use that, you would then need to prepend `/mnt/c` to any full path you want stat-ed (relative paths would need to be converted). So you are right, this can work on Windows without GfW installed, good work. (I have been avoiding the bash-subsystem due to the difficulty of integrating it with non-bash-subsystem tools.)

Comment: As a (late) follow-up: for R to be able to use the WSL-based utilities, you would need to be running R within the WSL itself. As it stands, R-in-windows can execute windows binaries; R-in-wsl can execute the linux binaries; neither system can execute the other binary format. So though @HongOoi's comment about being able to use the WSL shell is correct, it is not without limitation or consequence.

Answer (score 6):

You can wait about 2 weeks, at which point R 3.3.3 will solve this problem (at least for Windows). From the [NEWS](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/html/NEWS.html) file:

> (Windows only.) file.info() now returns file timestamps including fractions of seconds; it has done so on other platforms since R 2.14.0. (NB: some filesystems do not record modification and access timestamps to sub-second resolution.)

Comment: Neat! That's great for Windows. I'm probably out of luck for [Mac OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403588/how-to-return-millisecond-information-for-file-access-on-mac-os-x-in-java), though.